# Problem generating references by chapter

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, auxiliary-files

as the title says I have a problem trying to show the references of a chapter at the end of it. With this code I get the same references (all of them) at the end of each chapter. I have one `.bib` with al references.

I'm using TeXstudio 2.12.16 and MiKTeX 2.9

This is the code of the main `.tex`

```
%% PREAMBLE  PREAMBLE  PREAMBLE %%  
%% PREAMBLE  PREAMBLE  PREAMBLE %%


%Tipo de Documento
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{book}

%Diseño de pagina
%\usepackage[left=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} 
 \setlength{\hoffset}{0mm}
 \setlength{\voffset}{0mm}
 \setlength{\headsep}{4mm} %distancia del encabezado al cuerpo del documento
 \setlength{\oddsidemargin}{4.79mm}
 \setlength{\evensidemargin}{4.79mm}
 \setlength{\topmargin}{0mm} %distancia del filo superior de la hoja al encabezado
 \setlength{\textwidth}{150mm} %Ancho del cuerpo del documento
 \setlength{\textheight}{219mm} %Largo del cuerpo del documento
 \setlength{\parskip}{2ex}
 \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

%Diseño de cabeceras y pies de pag
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\let\headwidth\textwidth
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\newcommand{\size}{\fontsize{10}{11}\selectfont}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\size\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\size\rightmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\size\thepage}
\fancyfoot[C]{\size Luis Pulido L\'opez}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\size Noviembre/2019}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

%Numeracion de paginas
\usepackage{chappg} %numeracion tipo capitulo-pagina añade la opcion 
            %bychapter al comando 

%diseño de pies de foto
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\belowdisplayshortskip
  \hfil\parbox{1\textwidth}{\centering\footnotesize{#1}. {#2}\\}\hfil%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip}
\makeatother

%Idioma y tipos
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} %idioma español
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %introducir caracteres castellanos
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{latexsym} %para introducir simbolos

%Graficos e hiperenlaces
\usepackage{graphicx} %para incluir graficos
\usepackage{color} %para dar opciones de color
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf} 
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref} %para incluir enlaces en pdf
\usepackage{bookmark,hyperref}

%Formulacion matemaica
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{eurosym}




\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

%Cambiar Cuadros por Tablas y lista de...
    \addto\captionsspanish{%
    \def\bibname{Referencias}%
    \def\tablename{Tabla}%
    \def\listtablename{\'Indice de Tablas}
    \def\technicalreportname{Informe t\'ecnico}%
  }

%%% Add by user (package to get colors)
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{gris-claro}{gray}{0.82}


%Miscelania
\usepackage{lettrine} %Letras capitales
\usepackage{chappg}   %Numeracion de paginas por cap
\usepackage{lscape}   %Para introducir hojas apaisadas (landscape) en mitad del texto
\usepackage{scalefnt} %Material escalat
\usepackage{longtable} % para tablas de varias páginas
\usepackage{rotating} %Para introducir hojas apaisadas (landscape) en mitad del texto
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

%Bibliografia
\usepackage[nobreak]{cite}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib} %bibliografia por capitulos

%Indice bibliografico
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand{\ii}[1]{{\itshape #1}}
\makeindex

%% END OF PREAMBLE  END OF PREAMBLE  END OF PREAMBLE %% 
%% END OF PREAMBLE  END OF PREAMBLE  END OF PREAMBLE %%

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Document
\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{spanish}
%Identificaci�
\includepdf{portada_electronica}

%\maketitle 
\thispagestyle{empty} % para que no se numere esta página
\clearpage
% \clearpage
\newpage
\mbox{}
\makeatletter %para incluir numero romanos en minuscula
\def\@roman#1{\romannumeral #1}
\makeatother
\pagenumbering{roman}

%Preliminars
\input{capitulos/preliminares.tex}

%Taules de continguts
{\setlength{\parskip}{0ex}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    \tableofcontents
    \listoffigures
    \listoftables}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Página en blanco para que el comienzo de capítulo sea hoja impar
\clearpage

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\thispagestyle{empty}
\phantom{Whazaaap}
\clearpage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Capitulos
\pagenumbering{bychapter}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\parskip}{2ex}

\input{capitulos/introduccion.tex}

\input{capitulos/seleccion_regulador.tex}

\input{capitulos/diseno_implementacion_circuito.tex}

\input{capitulos/estudio_comparado.tex}

\input{capitulos/conclusiones.tex}

\input{capitulos/lineas_futuras.tex}

\appendix

\input{capitulos/presupuesto.tex}
\input{capitulos/instrumentacion.tex}
\input{capitulos/resistencias_regulacion_carga.tex}


\end{document}
```

And at the end of every chapter I put this code

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{myTFG}
```

I have tried to compile PdfLaTeX then compile bibliography for every chapter and after compile twice PdfLaTeX.

One this is that the program doesn't generate a `.aux` file for every chapter, neither a `.bib` or `.bbl` file, only for the main file and the main bibliography.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider using biblatex, which has native support of your required feature and well documented aswell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer myself:

- First of all add `\usepackage{natbib}` (idk if this is relevant but it works for me).
- Then change `\input` by `\include` on every capter in order to generate de `.aux` files.
- Compile the pdf and then open the `.aux` and compile the bibliography of every `.aux` files that should include the references.
- Compile twice the pdf.
- Done!

One more step for me was change the path of the `.bib` because it was written with "problematic" characters.

Answer (score 2):

You must run bibtex on each included file individually. Compile complete document and then

```
bibtex introduccion
bibtex seleccion_regulador
etc.
```

the compile again two times complete docuemnt

Comment: What do you mean with "run bibtex"? In the code of the main .tex file? Because I have only one bibtex file that is myTFG.bib with all the references